# Great UIKit/Objective-C code snippets

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, uikit

New to Objective-C iPhone/iPod touch/iPad development, but I'm starting to discover lots of power in one-liners of code such as this:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 10;
```

Which will display that distinctive red notification badge on your app iphone with the number 10.

Please share you favorite one or two-liners in Objective-C for the iPhone/iPod touch/iPad here.  **PUBLIC APIs ONLY**.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Open an URL in Safari**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]];
```

**Hide the status bar**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

**Dial a Phone Number (iPhone Only)**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://9662256888"]];
```

**Launch the Apple Mail**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto://mymail@myserver.com"]];
```

**stop responding to touch events**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

**active the touch events**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

**Show the network Activity Indicator**

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
```

**Hide the network Activity Indicator**

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
```

**Prevents iPhone goes into sleep mode**

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 14):

1. Display an alert window:

   ```
   UIAlertView* alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"too many alerts" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
   [alert show]
   ```
2. Get the path to the Documents folder:

   ```
   NSArray*  paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
   NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   ```
3. Push another view controller onto the Navigation Bar:

   ```
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherVC animated:YES];
   ```
4. Fade away a UIView by animating the alpha down to 0:

   ```
   [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
   [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];  // fade away over 1 seconds
   [aView setAlpha:0]; 
   [UIView commitAnimations];
   ```
5. Get the name of the app

   ```
   self.title = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleName"];
   ```
6. Change the status bar to black

   ```
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
   ```
7. Change the style of the navigation bar (from in a view controller):

   ```
   self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
   ```
8. Save a NSString into NSUserDefaults:

   ```
   NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   [defaults setObject:loginName forKey:kUserLoginName];
   ```
9. Get an NSString from NSUserDefaults:

   ```
   NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   ```

   NSString* loginName = [defaults stringForKey:kUserLoginName];
10. Check to make sure an objects support a method before calling it:

    ```
    if ([item respondsToSelector:@selector(activateBOP:)]) {
        [item activateBOP:closeBOP];
    }
    ```
11. Log the name of the class and function:

    ```
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    ```
12. Add rounded corners and/or a border around any UIView item (self)

    ```
    self.layer.borderColor  = [UIColor whiteColor].
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 8;     // rounded corners
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;  // prevent drawing outside border
    ```
13. Open Google Maps app with directions between two lat/long points

    ```
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f&dirflg=d", start.latitude, start.longitude, finish.latitude, finish.longitude];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    ```

Comment: `-[UIAlertView show]` returns `void`. Hence, you're leaking memory.

Comment: oops, I was trying to shorten it and messed it up.  I'll fix it, thanks!

Comment: No problem! Sometimes, I wish all methods returned `self`; then, I think back to old NeXTSTEP code and remember why not… :)

Comment: Those were the days, where an almost an entire program could fit on one line :)

Answer (score 10):

Save bool to User Defaults

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"Yes Bool"];
```

Copy a file from x to y

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:x toPath:y error:nil];
```

Display a new view

```
[self presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *) animated:YES];
```

Screen touches method

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {}
```

Get documents directory

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Load URL

```
[MyWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://couleeapps.hostei.com"]]];
```

Get Current Date and time:

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Own enum type:

```
typedef enum {
    a = 0, b = 1, c = 2
} enumName;
```

Quartz draw arc

```
CGContextRef ctxt = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextAddArc(ctxt, x, y, radius, startDeg, endDeg);
```

Comment: It is -setBool:forKey: not -setBool:ForKey: so you might want to fix that.

Answer (score 8):

Make the device vibrate:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

Open the Messages app with a specific phone number:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sms:123456789"]];
```

Stop responding to touch events:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

Start responding again:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

And finally, [the single line of code browser](http://geektime.wordpress.com/2008/04/10/a-single-line-of-code-browser-with-cocoa/):

```
[[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [urlText stringValue]]]];
```

Answer (score 5):

Change the title on the back button on a UINavigationView. Use this code on the UINavigationController before pushing the view

```
UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];


self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;
[backBarButtonItem release];
```