# what are the best code snippet sites for iphone / objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Great UIKit/Objective-C code snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018394/great-uikit-objective-c-code-snippets)

what are the best code snippet sites for iphone / objective c

Comment: Already answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018394/great-uikit-objective-c-code-snippets

Comment: @herbalessence If it's already been answered mark this question as a duplicate.

Comment: @herbalessence Yet you haven't. (To mark as a duplicate, click the close link, then select "exact duplicate", etc.) That said, I'd personally say the question you linked to above is slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

You can try iphone cookbook. If you don't want to buy it, small samples are available at google books:
http://books.google.de/books?id=K28J48Gia3UC

Answer (score 0):

Read [Programming in Objective-C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321566157) by Stephen G. Kochan.
Btw, a good link here. Go through it : [A Code Library for iPhone Objective-C Applications](http://cplus.about.com/od/codelibraryforiphone/A_Code_Library_for_iPhone_Objective-C_Applications.htm)

Comment: See for link provided in comment section of your question. Read it